# Regular expression for variable name

Tags: regex, expression, bison, flex-lexer

I'm still using `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_$0-9]` as a regular expression for catching a variable name (in bison-flex). Now I want to add dot and square bracket into it.
For example it could be `abc.def[12]`. How can I do it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Shouldn't it be `[A-Za-z][][A-Za-z_$0-9.]*`?

Comment: Do you really want `abc.def[12]` to be a single identifier? Because it looks like a member access, followed by an array access, which should not be a single token. Or is that just a coincidence and, say `abc].]]def[` would be an equally valid identifier in your language?

Comment: I use flex-bison for parsing query condition (mongodb). It's  actually colunm name. Columns names are similar object filelds. I need to get it as identifier  and use it for creating query.

Comment: If you don't care about _form_ just use the regex suggested above, which matches `abc.def[12]` btw.

Comment: @user3379281: So, tried `[A-Za-z][].[A-Za-z_$0-9]*`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know bison-flex but i think the regex you are looking for is:

`[A-Za-z][\w$]*(\.[\w$]+)?(\[\d+])?`

But this is not the whole story as it would match within otherwise invalid variable names (as do all the other patterns mentioned in the comments above)

For example would match `abc.def[12]` inside the string `123abc.def[12]456` you need to be very careful with false positives when working with regular expressions.

So you need an anchor, a negative look behind and look ahead (does bison-flex allow these?).
The final regex would look something like this:

`(?<![\w\d\.\[\]$])[A-Za-z][\w$]*(\.[\w$]+)?(\[\d+])?(?![\w\d\.\[\]$])`

The negative look behind `(?<![\w\d\.\[\]$])` ensures the start of the match occurs on a character that is not \w (a word character) \d (a digit) a dot square brackets or a dollar.

The same is true for the negative look ahead `(?![\w\d\.\[\]$])` This ensures the end of the match is immediately followed by a character that is not \w (a word character) \d (a digit) a dot square brackets or a dollar.

a list of matches:

- abc.def[12]
- abc.def
- abcdef[12]
- abc.def12
- abc
- abc_12
- abc._$
- a_$
- a_$12.a_$12

And a list of non matches

- _abc
- $abc
- abc.def[]
- 12abc.def[12]
- abc.def[12]12
- _abc.def[12]
- $abc.def[12]
- abc.def[12]$
- [12]abc.def
- abc[12].def

Again i dont know bison-flex but be aware the look behind and look ahead are not comprehensive, for example a match of `abc.def[12]` would be found in the string `#abc.def[12]%` But I don't know if this would be a problem for you or not!